# What is sequence coverage?

Tags: ruby, code-coverage, simplecov, shippable-ci

I am using simplecov for code coverage. I have no idea what sequence coverage is. I Googled it but I could not find anything, although I did find information about Branch Coverage.

Here is what I see in Shippable CI:
[image]

Comment: Did your coverage report show anything with respect to the Sequence? It will be helpful if you can share that.

Comment: I pulled the source code of simplecov and there's no mention for "sequence" in the codebase. Are you sure Sequence isn't one of your own files?

Comment: @WandMaker, question updated

Comment: @kimmmo question updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "Sequence coverage" comes from Shippable CI, not simplecov.

From [Shippable's API documentation](http://docs.shippable.com/api/) we can find this:

> **branchCoveragePercent** The percentage of branches (if/then/else condtions) that are covered by tests
>
> **sequenceCoveragePercent**   Percentage of lines there are code coverage for

So branch coverage counts all your code branching such as:

```
if a==b
  do stuff            # branch 1
else
  do other stuff      # branch 2
end
```

Now if your test suite only tests when a==b, your *branch coverage* for this file is 50%.

Sequence coverage is the regular line by line coverage report, if your code has 100 lines and during the tests only 70% of the lines have been run, your *sequence coverage* is 70%.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently "Sequence Coverage" is a Shippable CI term. According to [Shippable CI's docs](http://docs.shippable.com/api/), "sequence coverage" just means line coverage. Perhaps they chose that term to contrast to "branch coverage".